# HTTP Method OPTIONS: Which part of code is making this call?

Tags: admin-on-rest

I use admin-on-rest (version 1.3.1)

My server calls are authenticated (JWT Token); and every call requires to pass in an authorization header.

The OPTIONS .../api/v1/resource fails because it is missing authorization header.

If I open up (grant permission for OPTIONS to by-pass security); the calls complete successfully.

Is there a way to intercept and add authorization header to OPTIONS API calls?

Any thoughts will help.

Comment: What REST client are you using?

Comment: SimpleRestClient from admin-on-rest

Comment: simple rest client does not make options calls. I don't know how it is working at all for you. For making such specific requests you need to write your own Rest client, there you can also set the Auth header.

Comment: I've customized httpClient to inject Auth Headers.

const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers();
    }

    if(!url.endsWith("/authenticate") && localStorage.getItem('token') !== null) {
      options.user = {
        authenticated: true,
        token: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      }
    }

    return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
}

const restClient = SimpleRestClient(Constants.API_BASE_URL, httpClient);

Comment: Here is what happens: I see OPTIONS calls for all endpoints defined with <Resource ... /> element within <Admin>

Request URL: .../api/v1/activities/9J0b2e0g
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:10078
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Above call will be followed by

Request URL: .../api/v1/activities/9J0b2e0g
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:10078
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: Allowing preflight requests fixed the problem.  This can be marked as an acceptable solution.

Comment: Hey man. Sorry I was kinda offgrid. But great to know you found a good solution. Please make it into an answer then. I will upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this issue: When implementing security, preflight requests must be opened up for all (ex: OPTIONS for /** resources must not be secured).  This is required for browsers to complete preflight requests successfully.